# Como aumento la cantidad de datos que puedo extraer con wcf ya que el que trae por defecto no me sirve

Tags: c#, wcf

**El siguiente es mi código no se porque no me reconoce las propiedades, necesito poder traer mas informacion que la que viene por defecto, ya cambie el maxreceivedmessage, el buffer he hecho de todo lo que he leido sin encontrar respuesta**

````
```<system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding >
              <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
              <binding name="ServiceBinding" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
              </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
    
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
      <services>
          <service name="wcf.Service1">
              <host>
                  <baseAddresses>
                      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/wcf/" />
                  </baseAddresses>
              </host>
              <!-- Service Endpoints -->
              <!-- A menos que esté completa, la dirección está en relación con la dirección base suministrada anteriormente -->
              <endpoint name="ServicePDS" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding" contract="wcf.IService1">
                  <identity>
                      <dns value="localhost" />
                  </identity>
              </endpoint>
          </service>
      </services>
  </system.serviceModel>```
````

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.